# In javascript, which is better `var Obj = Obj || {}` or `if (Obj === 'undefined' || typeof Obj !== 'object')`

Tags: javascript

I want to know which of these methods is better:

```
var Obj = Obj || {};
```

or

```
if (Obj === undefined || typeof Obj !== 'object') {
  Obj = {};
}
```

I've been told that the 2nd method is better, but I don't know why. Please can you explain to me what are pros and cons of each.

Many thanks

Comment: Those pieces of code don't do the same thing... Also I don't think you meant to write `Obj === 'undefined'`, but rather `Obj === undefined` or `typeof Obj === 'undefined'`.

Comment: @AlinPurcaru: Even `Obj === undefined` and `typeof Obj === 'undefined'` would make no sense because the second condition would catch it anyway. It looks to me like the author of the second thing didn't think about the code.

Comment: @thejh: Yes I thought about the code, that's why I'm asking a question. I was using the 1st method before but someone told me it's a bad idea... And he told me to use the 2nd method instead.

Comment: Your second method is redundant because `typeof undefined` is "undefined", which of course, is not equal to "object".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second method is simply more specific, so for the purpose of creating an object (if it does not already exist), it is better. The first method only tests if the object is "truthy", meaning if `Obj` was the number 5, it would still return the original `Obj`, whereas in the second method, `Obj` *must* be of type 'object' in order for its value to be preserved.

Practically speaking, there isn't much of a difference, because you rarely run into situations like above; the second method just tells the reader what you want, more specifically. I like the first method because it's shorter, but it depends on how specific you want to be.

Answer (score 2):

The only issue I see with the first method is that if someone has defined `Obj` to refer to something that isn't an object but also isn't falsey -- a non-zero integer, say -- then `Obj` will continue to point to that thing, and later calls to `Obj` that assume it is an object will fail.  But I still prefer the first version for simplicity; I try to namespace such objects in such a way that no one will have assigned anything inappropriate to that name.