# Differences in namespacing

Tags: javascript, performance, namespaces

I was considering different types of namespacing and wondering which is best to use.

I personally use the following:

```
var App = {

    foo: function(){},
    bar: function(){}

}
```

But I have noticed some guru's are using a bit of a different technique and I was wondering why the extra step.

```
 var app = app || {}
```

Is it done out of necessity or complexity? Which would you recommend using?

Comment: possibly duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7971147/in-javascript-which-is-better-var-obj-obj-or-if-obj-undefined

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The construct you're asking about is not about namespacing, per se.  It's just a way of not clobbering an existing value (or namespace, if you will).

If you think `App` might already exist, and you don't want to overwrite it with your implementation, you would use something like this:

```
var App = App || {};
App.foo = function(){};
App.bar = function(){};
```

Of course, if `App` *does* exist, and has properties `foo` and/or `bar`, you will clobber those.

Proper namespacing allows the *caller* to decide what something's called.  For example, let's say your project wants to export `App`.  But what if the caller is already using `App`; now the onus is on *them* to change the name.  A better way to go is let them decide what to call it.  Namespacing in Node works this way:

```
var http = require('http');
var myHttp = require('http');
```

Both `http` and `myHttp` are instances of the `http` package, but the caller gets to decide what they're actually called.

The Browserify (https://github.com/substack/node-browserify) project allows Node-style packages in the browser, which is pretty handy.  It seems to be getting very popular.