# not sure how to ask this but what are they trying to do here?

Tags: javascript

In JS what are they saying on the following line?

```
members = members || {};
```

I'm confused by the OR operator. Are they saying if it if members is not null make it equal to members OR create a new object?

Comment: Not an exact duplicate, but pretty close: [*In javascript, which is better `var Obj = Obj || {}` or `if (Obj === 'undefined' || typeof Obj !== 'object')`*](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7971147/in-javascript-which-is-better-var-obj-obj-or-if-obj-undefined).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's saying that if `members` is something that is **not** `undefined` or "falsey" then it will set it to `members` otherwise it will set it to a new empty JavaScript object.

This type of code is often used if the code is run through more than once. The first time through `members` would normally be `undefined` but subsequent times it would have a value you didn't want to lose.

Things to watch for with these types of statements: some real values like `0` or `false` will evaluate to a "falsey" condition. In this case that's not an issue. In the future if you use something like that keep that in mind. Anything "falsey" will default to the "other side" of the `||` statement. In this case the `{}`.

Comment: Thank you. Making sense now.

Comment: @Editor I'm glad I could be of service. Keep in mind to mark the most appropriate answer as the answer by checking the check box under the voting controls. This is for the community, yourself later, and for the one answering.

Answer (score 2):

```
members = members || {};
```

This means if members variable is not undefined then `members == members` else `members == {}`

This case is used where members returns object({}) then use `members` and if members doesn't return the object then use `{}`

Answer (score 2):

It uses Javascripts return values for the || operator, which is "return the first thing that is truthy"

So in this case, it will return members if members exists, otherwise it will return {}.

It's a quick way to set things if they aren't set yet (for example to implement default arguments to functions)

Answer (score 0):

They are saying, if the variable members doesn't exist, declare it as an empty object.

if it DOES exist, use it

EDITED:
As pointed out members must be a 'falsey' value to be reset to an empty object.
Be careful if there is a chance members can be set to 0, empty string etc when using this technique.

Answer (score 0):

This basically means if members already exists use that, else create a new object.